# Converting two shorts to IEEE754 single precision float

Tags: c#, converters, endianness, ieee, ushort

i'm using Modbus TCP to read data of a device. The data is mostly single precision floating point integers (IEEE754) stored as two 16 bit values. Now i need to convert the two shorts to a float.

An Example: The conversion of ushort[] { 17253, 46620 } should yield 229.711365.

I think the problem is that the device uses big endian and i'm working on a PC with little endian. My current approach is:

```
ushort[] received = new ushort[]{ 17253, 46620 };
byte[] asByte = new byte[] {
    (byte)(received[1] % 256),
    (byte)(received[1] / 256),
    (byte)(received[0] % 256),
    (byte)(received[0] / 256),
};
float result = BitConverter.ToSingle(asByte, 0);
```

I was hoping there is a shorter way and maybe a way that works on a big endian pc, too.

I also don't understand why this does not work:

```
ushort[] received = new ushort[] { 17253, 46620 };
byte[] asByte = new byte[4];
Buffer.BlockCopy(received, 0, asByte, 0, 4);
float result = BitConverter.ToSingle(asByte, 0);
```

Comment: There's no endianness problem here, hard to guess what you want to do differently.

Comment: I've edited my question to include the source of my confusion :). If you could explain why this does not work i would be happy.

Comment: You just have 17253 and 46620 reversed.  Use `new ushort[] { 46620, 17253 }` instead.  That's not an endianness problem.

Comment: @HansPassant in the actual situation i don't get to choose the order but you are right with your solution :). Thanks a lot. Thats not an endianness problem? i'm still confused about this.